# No result defined for action action.ArticleAction and result input

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to show a list of all articls in my jsp pages. I'm using struts. My listArticles function throws an error as described follows.

Article Action:

```
package action;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import dao.Article;
import service.ServiceArticle;
public class ArticleAction extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String designation;
private double prix;
List<Article> listArticle;
ServiceArticle serviceArticle = new ServiceArticle();

@Override
public void validate() {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(getDesignation())) {
        addFieldError(designation, "Saisir la designation");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(getPrix()))) {
        addFieldError(designation, "Saisir la designation");
    }
}

public String execute() {
    Article article = new Article(designation, prix);

    if (serviceArticle.addArticle(article)) {
        listArticle = serviceArticle.getAllArticle();
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public String listArticles() {

    listArticle = serviceArticle.getAllArticle();
    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @return the designation
 */
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

/**
 * @param designation
 *            the designation to set
 */
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

/**
 * @return the prix
 */
public double getPrix() {
    return prix;
}

/**
 * @param prix
 *            the prix to set
 */
public void setPrix(double prix) {
    this.prix = prix;
}

/**
 * @return the listArticle
 */
public List<Article> getListArticle() {
    return listArticle;
}

/**
 * @param listArticle
 *            the listArticle to set
 */
public void setListArticle(List<Article> listArticle) {
    this.listArticle = listArticle;
}
}
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="default"  extends="struts-default">
    <action name="Ajouter">
        <result>/Article.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="Article" class="action.ArticleAction" >
        <result name="success">/ListArticle.jsp</result>
<!--            <result name="error">/Article.jsp</result> -->
        </action>
        <action name="listArticle" class="action.ArticleAction" method="listArticles">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/ListArticle.jsp</result>
        </action>
   </package>

</struts>
```

ListArticle.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Liste des Articles</h3>
    <%--    <s:property name="listArticle" /> --%>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DESIGNATION</th>
                <th>PRIX</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="listArticle">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="designation" /></td>    <td><s:property value="prix" /></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I fix?

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.

Comment: sorry, the server generate this error : No result defined for action action.ArticleAction and result input

Comment: Looks like the server is right - there is none.

Comment: thanks Aleksandr M, but where is the problem in that code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to stem from the logic you have in your `validate()` method.

When your action mapping for `listArticles` is called, the `validate()` method will also still be called because the validation framework will attempt to first call `validateListArticles()` and then will call `validate()`.  If either of the two validate methods exist, they'll be invoked after which the validation framework verifies whether any action or field errors exist.  If they don't, the action's method handler is called; otherwise the validation framework will ask the dispatcher to return result named 'input'.

In your action mapping, since `listArticles` does not have a result named input defined with what struts should do in this case, you receive the error message as you described.

If the validation logic in `validate()` is only applicable to when you are rendering the view for a single article, I might invert your action mappings as follows:

```
public class ArticleAction extends ActionSupport {
   @Override
   public String execute() throws Exception {
     /* logic to fetch all articles */
   }
   public void validateShowArticle() {
     /* do your article view validation */
   }
   public String showArticle() {
     /* logic to fetch a single article */
   }
}
```

Then your struts.xml

```xml
<action name="listArticles" class="ArticleAction">
  <result name="success">/listartitlces.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="article" class="ArticleAction" method="showArticle">
  <result name="success">/showarticle.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/showarticle-error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

With this configuration, the validation is specific to a special method handler, in this case `showArticle` rather than being global for all methods inside the action.

If you don't want to invert your action methods, you could rename `validate()` to `validateExecute()` and accomplish the samething.

But I often view `execute()` much like the `validate()` method; they're meant to be global handlers for an action.